# Alarm Manager Example does not work

Tags: android

I am trying to follow the example [given here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459058/alarm-manager-example) on running some code in fixed time intervals. I used the code in this example (setting the waiting time to 1 minute instead), compiled it, started in on my phone, stopped the application on the phone, and waited for several minutes.

However, no `Toast` was shown and neither any log-entry. I also notice that the `Service.onStart` seems depreciated.

Is something missing in the example? Do I need to register something when the main activity of the app is started? Or call it from somewhere else in my app? Or maybe something is wrong in the manifest?

`AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mypackage.test" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <application>
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/stoxx"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" >

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".NewEntryActivity"
            android:label="@string/menu_add"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        />
        <activity
            android:name=".UserSettingActivity"
            android:label="@string/menu_add"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            />
        <receiver
            android:process=":remote"
            android:name=".Alarm">
        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: How did you stop the app? What version of Android are you running it under? Btw, your first `<application>` tag is closed prematurely.

Comment: There is a button on the phone which says "Clear all", which I suppose is to stop all running apps. I updated the Question with hopefully the correct closing tag...

Comment: 1)The `>` goes after the `theme` attribute. 2) If you mean "Close all", then you're forcibly stopping the app, and your alarms will be cleared. 3) If you're running on KitKat or above, `setRepeating()` is no longer exact. Check the docs for [`AlarmManager`](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html).

Comment: I already started to read the documentation. But it does not explain HOW to implement this or HOW to call something! I can create a class derived from `AlarmManager` - but then what? Also, I want some code being called even if I kill the app. For example, I can kill my mail app. But still I get a notification when I receive an email.  How does this work?

Comment: Is the manifest correct now?

Comment: Sure it does: "If your application needs precise delivery times then it must use one-time exact alarms, rescheduling each time as described above." It means use `setExact()`, and when that fires, set it again for the desired interval. Also, your email app doesn't use `AlarmManager`. And, no, remove the `>` directly after `<application`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95830/discussion-between-alex-and-mike-m).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to include service in your Manifest. Here is all this project that works for me, check it.

Here is my manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.alarmmanager.just_me.alarmmanager">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<application android:allowBackup="true" android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver android:process=":remote" android:name=".Alarm"/>
    <service android:name=".MyService"/>
</application>
```

Here is Alarm:

```
public class Alarm extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "");
    wl.acquire();

    // Put here YOUR code.
    Toast.makeText(context, "com.alarmmanager.just_me.alarmmanager.Alarm !!!!!!!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // For example

    wl.release();
}

public void SetAlarm(Context context)
{
    AlarmManager am =( AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent i = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000 * 5, pi); // Millisec * Second
}

public void CancelAlarm(Context context)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.cancel(sender);
}}
```

Here is service:

```
public class MyService extends Service
{
    Alarm alarm = new Alarm();
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        Log.d("!~!", "Service started.");
        alarm.SetAlarm(this);
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId)
    {
        alarm.SetAlarm(this);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

And the last one MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
        startService(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Together with the suggestion from Mike it seems to work! Thanks a lot!!